# Set destination location with respect to file extension at run time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I have one requirement, I want to set destination location based on the file extension from the source location for example, In the source location i have the following files abc.txt ,mno.txt, pqr.csv and xyz.pdf . Once the adapter start polling , abc.txt and mno.txt will have move txtDesinationPath pqr.cv will have to move csvDestinationPath and xyz.pdf will have to move pdfDesinationPath respectively. Could you please suggest me some logic to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which technology? You tagged aws - do you mean s3, sns?

e.g. the S3 handler has `bucketExpression` which is a SpEL expression evaluated against the message.

Comment: Yes. Its poll from S3 bucket only. Actually it will poll from one of the IN folder inside the S3 bucket . example : {bucketName/IN} . And in the IN folder location there are different types of file. Based on the file extension it has to transfer different destination folder in the local machine. Using s3 inbound adapter for this.

Comment: So, as I said, use the `bucketExpression` to select the bucket.

Comment: I tried this but instead of poll all files from IN folder the IN folder getting copied to the local directory. Used remote-directory-expression="'${bucketName/IN}'"

Comment: You need to edit your question to show your configuration and state **exactly** what your issue is.

Comment: Hi Gary,  As you suggested i have customized the bucketExpression for each destination . Now its works fine